# CSS select radiobutton of group before the check one

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, radio-button

I'm looking to style some radio buttons in a group. I cannot use any JS, so only css.

```
<input type="radio" name="attr_1" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="attr_1" value="2">
<input type="radio" name="attr_1" value="3">
<input type="radio" name="attr_1" value="4">
<input type="radio" name="attr_1" value="5">
```

With the :checked selector I can change the appearance for the selected input but I want to be able to select all radio buttons with a lower value than the one I have checked.

```
input[type='radio'] {
    background-color: red
}

input[type='radio']:checked + input {
    background-color: black
}
```

For example, if the radio button with value 3 is selected it will have a red background but I also want the 1 & 2 to have a red background. Using JS I would easily do this, but I can only use CSS.

Is there any way i can have all following inputs instead of only the 1 input behind the ckecked one?

Comment: with the css3 is hard to do this. is jquary allowed ?

Comment: sadly in the enviroment i'nm working no javascript is allowed at all.

Comment: @j08691 thx for running my spelling correction ;)

Comment: If you can reverse the order of the elements in the DOM, you can probably do this with `+` or `~` selectors. Using flex or positioning, you can reverse the visual order of the elements.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a "previous sibling" CSS selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-css-selector)

Comment: @mpro Ii know that there is no previous sibling selector, I was hoping for someone who could think of something more logic. i thought about stuff like comparing the values to eachother, but sadly css doesn't do that either.

Comment: @ProdigySim could you give me a exsample of what you thought? I thought about the + and ~ selectors as well, but came to no effect i could use. and i don't see a reason to invert the order or the items. if the order is the only problem i should be able to simple negate the syles. make everything red, apart from those behind selected

Comment: Fine, but read answers to that questions, some are interesting, and actually, it is a duplicate, saw few of these here, the last one yesterday ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @mpro I could figure out a way to get all my following Styles differentiated from the once before the checked element.

```
<input type="radio" name="attr_1" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="attr_1" value="2">
<input type="radio" name="attr_1" value="3">
<input type="radio" name="attr_1" value="4">
<input type="radio" name="attr_1" value="5">

input {
    background-color: red;
}
input:checked ~ input {
    background-color: black
}
```

this required me to have at least one Radiobutton selected, but i got that anyways. Thanks for all the help guys